# multer and express-validator error handling

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer, express-validator

I am trying to validate a form that contains an image using multer and other fields using express-validator , but in the post route always  get an undefined error (req.validationError) , any solution ?

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const { check, validationResult  , body} = require('express-validator');
var mkdirp = require('mkdirp');
var fs = require('fs-extra');
const path = require('path');
const multer = require('multer');
const cors = require('cors');
const morgan = require('morgan');
var rezizeimg = require('resize-img');
var adminrouter = express.Router();

adminrouter.post('/add_products',[check('description','description should not be empty ').notEmpty(),
        check('title','title should not be empy').notEmpty(),
        check('price','price should not be empty ').isDecimal()



],  (req,res)=> {
    let upload = multer({storage: storage, fileFilter: helpers.imageFilter}).single('profile_pic');

    upload(req, res, function (err) {
        // req.file contains information of uploaded file
        // req.body contains information of text fields, if there were any

        if (req.fileValidationError) {
            console.log(req.fileValidationError);
            return res.send(req.fileValidationError);
        } else if (!req.file) {
            filerror = 'Please select an image to upload';
        } else if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
            console.log(err);
            filerror = err;


        } else if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.send(err);

        }
```

**helpers.js**

```
const imageFilter = function(req, file, cb) {
    // Accept images only
    if (!file.originalname.match(/\.(jpg|JPG|jpeg|JPEG|png|PNG|gif|GIF)$/)) {
        req.fileValidationError = 'Only image files are allowed!';
        return cb(new Error('Only image files are allowed!'), false);
    }
    cb(null, true);
};
exports.imageFilter = imageFilter;
```

Comment: Visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63632356/multer-and-express-validator-creating-problem-in-validation
for the best response to your issue

Comment: [issue description & solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63632356/multer-and-express-validator-creating-problem-in-validation)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your helper only appends a fileValiditionError field to the request if the file is not an image. So if you are uploading a valid image there won't be a fileValiditionError  field in the request. You should only check from the error the upload function returned. If there is an error you can return an error message to the client

Comment: hi , even if the file is not an image the req.validationError is always undefined ?

Comment: Did you import your helper function into the server.js file?

Comment: yes I did, I think  body-parser no longer support multipart so I have to use busboy or multiparty